# Grub2 bootloader has issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Dell Inspiron with Windows 10 that was insanely and painstakingly slow after upgrading from Windows 7. It has 8 GB RAM and I tried numerous solutions to speed it up without luck. I then installed Ubuntu and Grub handled my boot options. I then had issues and did not uninstall Ubuntu properly. Long story short, my boot screen is somewhat buggy now.

I have a Legacy Mode that shows the options: Network, Hard Drive
I have a UEFI mode that shows HDD1 - ubuntu, HDD2 - Windows 10, HDD3 - Ubuntu. The 1st and 3rd options don't work. They result in the Grub shell loading and ending in an error.

I have tried repairing it using a live usb but that didnt work. I am not sure about the next set of steps to take at this point.

I can post detailed screenshots if that would help.

Edit1- I have reinstalled Ubuntu and I can get to it using the Hard Drive mode from the Legacy boot mode.

Comment: you need to reinstall ubuntu in EFI mode if you want to dual boot with windows.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. How do I clean up the non working Grub2 entries? Specifically HDD1 and HDD3.

Comment: open your EFI partition, and look for folders /EFI/Ubuntu/  delete them. then do a fresh install of Ubuntu. Leave the /EFI/BOOT/ and /EFI/Windows folders.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the /EFI/ubuntu, but some systems only want to boot from /EFI/Boot.  You may need to use efibootmgr to delete UEFI entires: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi